# How to get the windows session login from a webapps java?

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I'm currently developing a webbapps running on an apache tomcat 7 server. In this webapp I need to check the if the login used to log in the app is the same that the current windows session login so that only the owner of the computer can use the app in his computer. 
I tried to do something like this :

static boolean authentified(String username) {

```
boolean isAuth = false;

try {
    /*
     * verify if the user logged in windows is equal to the user who try
     * top connect System.getProperty("user.name") return the windows
     * session login
     */

    if (username.equals(System.getProperty("user.name"))) {

    isAuth = true;
    }

    System.out.println("return : " + isAuth + "\r\n");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    logger = AuthenticationImpl.initLog();
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
    fh.close();
}

return isAuth;

}
```

but since my webapp run on a server System.getProperty("user.name") is no longer retruning the windows session login.

Anyone knows how to pass the windows sessions login to the server ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [SPNEGO/Kerberos](http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/) if you are in a corporate network.